# Porting exisiting embedded source code to RTOS

Tags: c, embedded, porting, rtos

I have an existing embedded source code which runs directly on a microcontroller with no operating system. I need to port the code to run on a specific RTOS.

Are there any guidelines in where to start when attempting wuch a thing ?
Resources, best practices, and other insight will be much appriciated.

Comment: You should probably try to identify the atypical operations (peripheral configuration, interrupt handlers, etc) and separate those out from simple program logic so you can start to think how to implement/replace them in a way compatible with the RTOS. Then you need to look at the program organization - is it event driven, polling in a loop, etc?  Sometimes you can emulate a primitive environment in a richer one and keep most of the code unchanged, other times you'll really need to re-architect something that assumed the hardware was its to do with as it pleased to play nicely in an OS context.

Comment: The main question you have to answer first is: why do you "need" to port the code on a RTOS? Do you need to refactor your application to be able to handle parallel events more easily? Do you need to add new functionalities to the existing software that will need to be executed concurrently with the legacy code?

Comment: Does this RTOS have a name?  I'm generally of the mindset that once you've used (mastered) one or two, they're all pretty much the same, but still it might help to know if you're talking about uC/OS-II (small) vs. OSE or VxWorks or whatever...

Comment: @greydet - Absolutely agree.  Why (MellowCandle) do you "need" to port to this OS?  You know what I often tell customers in this situation?  Create a single task, put the current application in that task, bam, you're pretty much done.  Sure, in that case you're not exploiting the RTOS, but you didn't tell us you need to reduce polling / add a protocol stack / etc.  (Obviously if you're using interrupts, your work is a tad more than putting the application in a task).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RTOS preemptive multitasking is all about I/O performance.  You need drivers that can make a thread ready when I/O is complete, eg. by signaling a semaphore.  Nothing else is remotely as important.

Sadly, this usually means a system redesign to eliminate the performance-crippling polling that existed before :((

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the RTOS has to be ported on your microcontroller.
If the RTOS already supports your microcontroller, then next would be tweaking your code for the RTOS. For that you need to refer the user guide of RTOS.